# Load Outlook 2003 VSTO plugin

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, vsto

I have an annoying problem.
I have a VSTO 2 plugin for Outlook 2003 (written with VS2005).
I simply create 2 buttons that save email objects and work on emails.

The problem is that the plugin, when just installed, is loaded by outlook and it works, but when I reboot the plugin is no more automatically loaded. I must re-enable it from outlook's addin properties to see it again.
If I reinstall the plugin after reboot, (most of the times) it is again automatically loaded (till next reboot).

What could be the problem?

Comment: Looks like an unhandled exception in your add-in. Outlook will disable the add-in in that case.

Comment: i'm pretty sure there's no unhandled exception :/
at least not until i initialize the log. and in the case i don't see the addin ther's no log.
so my guess is that outlook doesn't even try to load it

Comment: Outlook probably doesn't try to load your add-in because it is already disabled due to a *previously* occurred exception. A way to debug this is to place a try/catch in all top-level methods and use `System.Diagnostics.Trace` to print the stack trace. Then use a tool like DebugView and you will possibly see what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have found to diagnose unhandled vsto exceptions is do the following:

-Open a command window
-type in "Set VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS = 1"
-type in "VSTO_LOGALERTS = 1"
run outlooks executable from its install location using the same command window.  In this manner I found my issue with an excel add in (it pops up a window instead of eating the error)